# Flutter - android - Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: android, flutter, dependencies, exoplayer

I am not able to use

```
flutter_html: ^2.2.1
```

and

```
audio_manager: ^0.8.2
```

in one project.
It shows error

> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
>
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
>
> Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.package-info found in modules jetified-exoplayer-common-2.14.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-common:2.14.1) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.11.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.11.1)
>
> Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project: `flutter clean`
Upgrade dependencies: `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`
Run the app. Let me know if you still had problem using those packages.

**Update:**
this seems to be a problem with `audio_manager`. try using `audio_service: ^0.18.3` instead. [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service)

Comment: No it didn't work, i still get same error.

Comment: I updated my answer. let me know if you still had a problem.

Comment: Thanks but i have change flutter_html to other library and keep audio_manager because i have implemented it in whole project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the version of exoplayer in the grade file